# What settings should I modify to tune a Linux server for very small yet very high packet rate UDP receive loads?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, udp, latency

I am tuning a server that needs to handle small (average of about 50 bytes) UDP packets. The average packet rate is approximately 100,000 packets/second. The data is very burst and can sometimes burst to 5x the mean packet rate.

What settings should I tune to ensure that I:

1. Minimize packet loss
2. Minimize kernel to user land latency

Comment: Trading system, right? There are some options. Can you provide details on the hardware specifications?

Answer (score 1):

There is little to do about this: install rt patch, have a nic that support polling, remove iptables rules. But a better ideea is to upgrade the hw; for a "mission critical" router, just buy a fast machine.